# Global log4j2-test.xml configuration

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, logging, log4j2

I have a multi-module maven Java project. When my unittests use log4j2, I place `log4j2-test.xml` file in `src/test/resources/` directory and this works fine.
Assuming I want to have the same log4j2 configuration in all the tests, I need to copy the same file to `resources` directory of every module I have.

Is there a way to use a single `log4j2-test.xml` file for all of my tests?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Maven module containing just your `log4j2-test.xml` as a resource and add it as a test dependency to your projects.